# Keyboard shortcut to move between tab groups in IE

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer

Are there any keyboard shortcuts to navigate between Internet Explorer's tab groups? Such that it's not necessary to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> over all the tabs in a group.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> moves to the first tab of the previous group and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to the first tab of the next group.

This skips tabs that are ungrouped, even if there's several of them next to each to each other.